Why do I have to increase the current by 2V when I am using a transistor?
I have a 3V 3W LED, which I would like to control with an ESP32.
For controlling the LED, I have chosen a TP122 transistor.
Here is my 'schematic':


The Arduino is an ESP in real life, and the 3 V battery is a 3V 3A power supply.
When I make the connections accordingly, only 0.1A goes to the LED (so it is very dim) when using a 3V power supply. When I replace the 3V power supply with a 5V 3A one, the LED is as bright as it is supposed to be.
When I directly connect the LED with the 3V 3A power source (seen in the following image,) the brightness is as expected.

Obviously, I need the transistor because 3W on 3V is 1.6A which would kill my microcontroller.
How can I use my 3V power supply with this method? Do I need another type of transistor?

Please don’t drive your NPN directly without a base resistor from your MCU. You may have damaged it. Moreover, you don’t increase current by 2 V, as volt is a unit of voltage, not current. A coin cell battery can not deliver 3 A.

You realise a fundamental design flaw is that your tiny little battery cannot supply anywhere near the current. Did you check the battery ratings when you selected it? Or just grab a battery that looked nice and small and assume it could power anything up to a lightsabre :-)

How does 3 V, 3 W amount to 1.6 A?

It is dim because the collector-emitter saturation voltage for your transistor is ~2V. Use a logic level MOSFET and a current limiting resistor. You won't be able to get full brightness with a 3V supply; if you want that, you'll have to boost above it and use an appropriate resistor or more exotic system to limit current.

So If I use a 5V power supply I would need a resistor somewhere? It is working without one. Am I damaging the LED this way?

Unless it's a current-limited module, yes.

Ideally, I would like to go the logic-level MOSEF way. Would the onsemi FQP30N06L meet my needs?

That should work. Use a pull-down to ground of about 10k and then a series gate resistor of about 100 ohms.

Sorry for being such an amateur, but If the voltage cannot raise above 3V, why do I need resistors?

You do still need a resistor. See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/is-a-current-limiting-resistor-required-for-leds-if-the-forward-voltage-and-supp

@Marci Can your controller output 5 V? Because 3.3 V won't be enough to reliably turn on an FQP30N06L.
